# Can I recover accidently deleted files on an SSD External Drive running Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I accidently deleted files from a WD external SSD hard drive.  Running OS is Windows 10.  I have scanned the drive with two separate on-line file recovery (Stellar & Recoverit) packages and both show the file structure with the free scan/  Purchased Stellar and recovered the files; however, I cannot open any of these files (pdf, docx, xlsx, pptx, etc.), instead get a corrupt file message.  Am I dead in the water, or do the service providers out there have more comprehensive tools?  I have heard something about Windows TRIM feature that could make this effort unsuccessful.

Comment: Yes, they're gone.

Comment: File recovery was fine back in the days of spinny rust HDDs. With SSDs, even unencrypted, you may as well consider it gone. Backups are even more important now than a decade ago.

Comment: Or just use spinny HDD for large external drives. Trim also doesn't happen on Flash drives so those are good for high speed and also recoverability.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but you found the answer yourself, the data was trimmed in your case.

It depends because:

- OS must support TRIM.
- OS must actually send the TRIM command. I have seen Windows suspend TRIM because of file system issues for example.
- File system, for example Windows does not TRIM FAT32 formatted drives.
- In case of external drives, the USB controller must pass on TRIM commands to the drive, something older USB adapters and enclosures didn't do.
- According several specs drives are free to ignore TRIM commands.

As a rule of thumb deleted data is trimmed when the data was stored on a SSD. But as we see there are conditions and exceptions. I therefor recommend you can try anyway. But chance you can actually recover the data is *poor*. If TRIM for whatever reason wasn't executed or dropped by the drive, chances are as with normal file deletion: deleted files can be recovered as long as:

- meta data for file still exists (not yet overwritten)
- actual data in cluster(s) still exists (not yet overwritten) <- TRIM affects this, when reading clusters the drive typically returns zero filled sectors.

Indeed it's not abnormal for undelete and file recovery tools to 'detect' the deleted files as file meta data does not get trimmed.

**File deletion on non-TRIM drive:**

[image]

**File deletion trimming drive:**

[image]

Images taken from: https://youtu.be/NyLQbxnPurc